# Question put on hold despite edit

Tags: discussion

I had asked this question yesterday and it was put on hold as it was deemed to be "opinion based". I was asked to re word this question to fit the rules.

[Is "our friends" being used sarcastically here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281640/why-is-our-friend-used-sarcastically-at-times)

I already did that but the question is still on hold. Is there any other reason for it to be on hold apart from the one that was stated?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question asked in your title, "Why is 'our friend' used sarcastically at times?", is unavoidably opinion-based; everyone has their own reasons for using sarcasm and we cannot reasonably enumerate the occasions when someone might decide to do so.

That said, since you edited the question to refer to a specific instance (regarding "our friends the Saudis"), the actual body of the question was an objectively answerable question ("yes, it's being used ironically to call attention to certain hypocritical political stances"); so I edited the title to match.  Perhaps it will be considered reopenable now.